# IE and Firefox neither read nor delete php session variables

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, firefox, cross-browser

First of all sorry for the possible duplicate. I noticed there are a lot of questions aubout the same case out there and I've read a ton of different answers. Seems like there can be several reasons for the session variables not to work but non of the given answers do the trick for me. Thats why I opened another question and hope you can help me.

I created the following two php files on my apache2 webserver (which is located on an openSuse 13.2 virtual server named 'asc-OpenLDAP')

The first file creates the session variable.

**test1.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
  header('Location: test2.php');
  exit();
?>
```

The second file should read the session variable and create an output.

**test2.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo("Test: " . $_SESSION['test']);
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  exit();
?>
```

So far I've tested the programm with some browsers. Vivaldi 1.8 shows the content of the session variable in test2.php correctly while Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox 51 wont.

Of course cookies are activated in alle three browsers.

I also checked for the session variable files at the session.save_path. All browsers generate a session file on the server. The content of this file always is `test|s:4:"test";`. But then again only Vivaldi is able to delete the file in test2.php.

As my programm gonna become an end-user tool I need to make it as compatible and dau-save as possible.
Please help me.

Comment: None of the data is stored in the browser, it's all stored server-side.  All that's stored on the browser is a cookie containing a session ID.  If some browsers are failing to display data in the session then they're probably not storing the session ID cookie, possibly due to whatever cookie policy you've set in the browser in question.  Firefox has a console that can show you things like what cookies the server sent and what cookies are being sent as part of a request, it may be worth checking to see what's going on with the session cookie.

Comment: True. That's why I checked it. ^^ The session date gets stored on the server with each of the browsers and it has the correct content. Firefox console says: 'Set-Cookie:"PHPSESSID=8c5hskk514dlkmpvn16k1mvn41sifcrmnnaadcoofsr979hlkpt1; path=/var/lib/php5/"' I think the problem lies more in accessing the already stored data as reading and deleting doesn't work with IE and Firefox.

Comment: With Chrome 56 its also not working. Same issue as with Firefox and IE.

Comment: Did the subsequent request send the appropriate Cookie header in the request?  If not then it still might be a client side cookie problem.  If the cookie is set then it could be a race condition, you may be getting redirected to test2.php before test.php has finished flushing the session data.  Maybe try replacing the Location redirect with a hyperlink just to see what happens?

Comment: Sadly a hyperlink instead of the redirect did not change anything. But I found out some other thing: On test1.php the session gets saved on the server. But after redirecting to test2.php the session id has changed. Maybe the cant match the received session id and creates a new one.

Comment: In other words: The session id stored in the cookie on the client equals the one stored in the session file on the server. But after the redirect the server can't match the received session id with the one it stored before and thus generates a new one which it sends back to the client. Again both server and client have the same session id but a different one than prior to the redirect.

Comment: Sounds a lot like FireFox/chrome etc are failing to store the cookies.  Just because there was a set-cookie header doesn't mean a cookie was actually set.  Like I said, look at what headers are sent in the request when you redirect to test2.php.  Also PHP can be configured to use query strings to pass session IDs but this is not recommended and should be disabled.  You might need to check how sessions are configured in php.ini

Comment: Here is the comparison between the session cookies created by the code on the client (left one is Vivaldi, right one is Firefox): http://666kb.com/i/dh2m5y0wz17jgc66a.jpg

Comment: Not sure what the stuff on the left says but if "pfad" means "path" then the path in firefox is very wrong.  It means the cookie will only be valid for http://your.domain.here/var/lib/php5

Comment: It's possible it works in Vivaldi but not in other browsers because Vivaldi might be ignoring the cookie path, while the other browsers are enforcing it as they should.  I'd recommend checking what the session cookie path is being set to because it almost certainly shouldn't be /var/lib/php5

Comment: The session.cookie_path in the php.ini is '/var/lib/php5' and all the session files show up at that location as expected. Meanwhile I monitored the request headers sent by Firefox. The log is here: http://freetexthost.com/2qegqcbrbz

Comment: There's your problem then.  The cookie path is meant to describe which website paths the cookie is valid for.  As stated above if the cookie path is `/var/lib/php5` then the cookie will only be returned to the server if the the path part of the URL starts with `/var/lib/php5`.  If you want the cookie to work everywhere in a particular domain the path has to be `/`.  I can only assume it worked in Vivaldi because it was ignoring the path constraint

Comment: Thats it! It works now. Thank you very much! Maybe someone should also tell the Vivaldi devs. @ GordonM: Would you please write out the answer as an actual answer so i can mark it as correct answer? That'd be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment conversation we were able to deduce the problem was that the path specified for the session cookie was incorrect.

The path associated with a cookie specifies which sections of a domain the cookie is valid for.  For example if you only want a cookie to be valid for `www.example.com/foo/bar/` then the cookie's path should be `/foo/bar/`  This means that the browser will only include the session cookie in the Cookie header if the URL you're visiting is `www.example.com/foo/bar/` or a subpath of it (for example `www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/quux.php`).  If you visit `www.example.com/foo/` then the cookie will not be sent back to the server in the Cookie header.

This is useful if you want to have different parts of a site to have different sessions (for example an e-commerce site might want to preserve different session data if you're in the admin section than if you're in the basket) but in this case the path was set incorrectly to a path that contained neither test1.php or test2.php.

You can set the path universally by specifying it in php.ini by setting a value for `session.cookie_path` (by default it should be `/` but for some reason it's not in your installation).

You can also set it on a per-script basis with [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

As for why it worked in Vivaldi the most probable explanation is that there's a bug in vivaldi that causes the path parameter on the cookie to be ignored.  You might want to file a bug report regarding this.  The behaviour in FireFox/IE/Chrome et all was the correct behaviour.